# What is the english translation of Russian dialog spoken over this song?

Tags: перевод

The song "Exploring Yourself With A Knife" is a track form the Russian post-rock band April Rain's album "Waiting For Sunrise". some Russian dialog is spoken between a man and a woman starting at 4:37. could someone provide a transcription or translation ?

The song could be found here on Last.fm:
[Exploring Yourself With A Knife](http://www.last.fm/music/April+Rain/_/Exploring+Yourself+With+A+Knife)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dialog from [The Fountain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0414993/).

See the first comment [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbrK6S_mwa4).